# Android out of memory exception

Tags: android, out-of-memory, assets, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

please help in solving me this out of memory exception as i am unable to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated,

```
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090): Process: com.zar.bdr, PID: 9090
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2113)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2095)
06-04 12:11:44.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9090):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
```

Comment: You have to show your code as `OME` can happen for diffrent reasons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: Are you converting image to bitmap large files or large number of files?

Comment: no, i am not converting any image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You can use `android:largeHeap="true"`in activity's manifest to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices.

**Solution 2:** Use an Image Loader library like,

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Which takes all the headache of loading a large image file, also supports some additional feature like caching and converting.

Comment: Please note that using android:largeHeap="true" is just a bandaid solution. In my experience, OutOfMemoryExceptions are due to leaking memory somewhere else in the app, and it's just manifesting itself here. You can use a library like LeakCanary to alert you when leaking an activity, and Android Studio's memory monitors to keep an eye on how much memory you're using.